# How to start the bat-file at Asp.net web server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, batch-file

I need to call a console application to load data into another desktop application on the remote server that located within the corporate domain.

Users will enter the web page and upload data to asp.net web server, which after transformation should call that console application. Users are located remotely and do not have any other access except the web server.

I decided to lower the security web application context and let the asp.net working process to start the console application on the current IIS 6.0 web server

What I have done:

- I changed the security account for the application pool for Local System;
- I added ASPNET Account and IIS_WPG IIS Process Account to Administrators group;
- I added “Allow service to interact with desctop” for “IIS Admin Service” and “World Wide Web Publishing Service” processes and restarted the machine;

I tried to start BAT-file at server side through the test page code-behind, but failed:

```
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process(); 
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @”C:\run.bat”; 
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();  
}
```

The error was `access denied.`

Please help me to find any workable idea how to start the bat-file at web server side.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this link, might work for you? http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2004/05/13/run-a-bat-file-from-asp-net/

Comment: Check the right on the C:\run.bat file itself.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `UseShellExecute` to true instead of false. After all, batch files run in a shell - so you *need* a shell to execute it. (Another option is to run cmd.exe and pass the name of the batch file in as an argument, e.g. "cmd.exe /k c:\run.bat")

You might also want to try creating a simple .NET app which just (say) creates a file with a timestamp in. That way you can test the "can I start another process" bit separately from the "can I get the batch file to work" bit.

Comment: I tried to run C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k c:\run.bat but server failed with error:  “The system cannot find the file specified.” but I executed it successfully in the “Start - Run” window.

Comment: @SystemObject: That does sound like a permissions fault, potentially. Have you tried the approach from my second paragraph?

Comment: I tried to create a new folder with a batch file in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot but failed.

Comment: @SystemObject: I wasn't suggesting creating a batch file though. I suggested a test executable file.

Answer (score 3):

Put that particular batch file in your application itself.

```
string str_Path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\run.bat";
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(str_Path);
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process batchProcess = new Process();
batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
batchProcess.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example: [Run Interactive Command Shell or Batch Files From ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Interactive_Command_Shell.aspx)

It uses little different approach. They suggest running cmd.exe and executing command line by line.

Comment: I do not understand if it works. I see successful messages, but no actions. Anyway I like  this idea.